# Dropdown is reloading home page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using a drop down for some additional content. I am not sure why but the drop down isn't working properly. When clicked on the 'read more' link it takes me back to my home page or refreshes to the home page. I made a jsfiddle and it's doing the same there. Any info on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

```js
$('.expand-notice').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    parent.toggleClass('open-notice');
    if (parent.hasClass('open-notice')) $(this).text('Less');
    else $(this).text('Read more');
  });
```

```css
.notice {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  max-width: 40em;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.notice p {
  margin: 0;
}
.notice-type,
.notice-title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.notice-type {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.notice-title {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.notice-content {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.notice-content p {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.open-notice .notice-content {
  display: block;
}

.recent-news {
  margin: 0em auto;
  max-width: 80em;
  padding: 0 3% 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.recent-news h2 {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.news-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
  width: 47.75%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em 0em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.news-item:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 3%;
}
.news-item p {
  padding: 0em 1.5em;
  margin: 0em;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.news-item p.news-date {
  font-size: 0.95em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" data-subject-page="1">
  <div class="largeText" data-subject-text="">
    <div class="recent-news">
    <h1>main title</h1>
      <div class="notice">
      <p class="notice-type">Date</a>
      <p class="notice-title">sub title</p>
        <div class="notice-content">
        <p>Content here</p>
        </div>
        <p><a href="/" class="expand-notice">Read more</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share a link to your jsfiddle?

Comment: [Looks OK to me](https://jsfiddle.net/ndwjbtmw/). Are you loading jQuery? Check you developer console for errors.

Comment: What do you suppose it to do? The `href` attribute is set to the home page of any web application.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***href*** attribute from a tag and wrap the scripts into

```
$(document).ready()
```

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muhammedbasilsk/ytsu088e/3/)

Answer (score 0):

As your Javascript code it suppose to show `Content Here Less`. Well. You have to do the following:

1- Be sure that you included the Jquery library

2- Place your Jquery code between script tag just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Checkout [**This DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/mexiha/1/)

If you want to place your script in the head section, you have to use `$document.ready(function(){// Your Code here});`